# Is it correct to say that acceleration slows the frequency of an oscillator?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, acceleration, observers

My question is based on differential aging or differential timekeeping due to, 1) increased speed, and 2) proximity to center of gravitational field.  As far as I know, both involve acceleration, and both affect the frequencies of oscillators in a predictable way.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your question is, something can have a large velocity with respect to another frame and appear to age more slowly to the external frame of reference with no acceleration involved. Of course this effect is symmetric as each frame can claim to be at rest.

Comment: well, if it's a pendulum with $g$ dependent period, it gets messy.